# Battery terminal corrosion?

Tags: battery, corrosion

[image: first terminal][image: second terminal]

I was preparing my motorbike for storage. When I was pulling the battery I noticed the terminal covered with what looks like corrosion or grease. Can anyone chime in?

This is brand new battery with less than 4 months.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from the pictures, but it could be Vaseline. A coating of petroleum jelly helps reduce corrosion and prevent dirt from getting into the contacts. I'd suggest leaving the Vaseline on while it's stored, then clean it off before reinstalling the battery.

Comment: If this is for long term storage (more than a few weeks) I suggest cleaning the bolt, screwing it back into the terminal, and then cleaning the grease off the terminal. Put the bolt back in to stop the dirty grease getting into the screw threads when you clean it! Then remove the bolt for the storage period.